# Facebook SDK Login callback is never called android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using the following code snippet in my Android app to allow users to login into my app using Facebook:

```
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    initCallback();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, FacebookUtils.requiredPermissions);
}

private void initCallback() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                   AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                }

            }
    );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

However, it's not working because the defined Callback methods are never called, I am shown the facebook loader and I am reaching onActivityResult but the callbacks are never called, does anyone know what might be the problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to sign in to Facebook as soon as you enter to this Activity or on button click?

Comment: @HelloWorld no, on a custom button click, not the facebook sdk login button

Comment: this was just an example to check if it is working and it is not reaching the defined callbacks

Comment: have you given permissions in manifest?

Comment: @VivekMishra I added the following in the manifest: <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

Comment: @VivekMishra is there also a permission that I did not define in manifest

Comment: you have posted activity tag , I am asking about permissions

Comment: @VivekMishra that's everything I added to manifest that is related to facebook, what is the permission that I should add?

Comment: atleast you must be giving internet permission in manifest. I am not specifically asking about facebook

Comment: Ofcourse I added internet permissions...

Comment: Set value of LoginManager.getInstance() to some vriable and use it

Comment: Put `Log.e("data",data.toString());` in `onActivityResult` and check what you are getting in it.

Comment: @jaydroider this is what i got in log Bundle[{com.facebook.LoginFragment:Result=com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Result@31bc7e98}]

Comment: @Yrgl did not work.. :(

Comment: @EyadMhanna Check my answer below. Let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    initCallback();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickLinew View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // add this on facebook sign in button click listener
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));
        }
    });
}

private void initCallback() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                   AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                }

            }
    );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: but that is exactly as my posted snippet, except the login request is inside the click listener which I already tried but with no success..

Comment: What difference it makes then OP.

Comment: `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));`
adding this code outside listener dint work for me bt on button click, it did.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this steps.**

Create new `Variable` for `LoginButton` define it Globally.

```
private LoginButton btnLogin;
```

Then on your `onCreate` add this Code.

```
btnLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday"));
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

**Also change this.**

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
```

**To this.**

```
btnLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager,
```

Comment: and what should I do in the onClickListener? also btnLogin is null what should I assign to it

Comment: @EyadMhanna Assign the id whatever you have in xml for Login Button.

Comment: can you explain what not working any new Logcat or having same problem as OP ?

Comment: same behavior as before, callback is not being called, thus I am not able to update the access token

Comment: Check this link for your reference this will help you http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/android-facebook-integration-sample.html

Comment: I can't be able to assume issue now follow link i have given will solve your problem.